# Linux: read xwd output with Java?

Tags: java, linux, screenshot, processbuilder, xvfb

I would like to execute a program in the Xvfb virtual frame buffer and then take a look at it within runtime. From wikipedia I know it is possible to get a screenshot-file like this:

```
Xvfb :1 &
xv -display :1 &
xwd -display :1 -root -out image.xwd
```

Is it possible to read and decode the xwd output directly with Java using ProcessBuilder or Runtime.exec() ?

Kind Regards,
Theo

Comment: Short answer: No.  Longer answer: Yes, if you do the decoding.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the question really is: if you leave out the `-out` option, xwd will output to stdout and then indeed you can read this directly from the process within Java. Afaik the xwd-format is not something very common today, so if the question is whether Java can decode and use it, I think the answer is 'no' and you need to run yet another command to convert it. For easier use in Java, you might want to take a look at import from imagemagick, as it is able to write more easily handled formats, like png or jpeg.